# Matlab solving ODEs can not understand this function description

Tags: matlab, ode

I have stumbled upon this matlab code that solves this ODE

```
y'''(t) + a y(t) = -b y''(t) + u(t)
```

but I am confused by the ode_system function definition, specifically by the `y(2) y(3)` part. I would greatly appreciate if someone can shed some light

`y(2) y(3)` part in the ode_system function confuses me and how it contributes to overaal solution

```
% Define the parameters a and b
a = 1;
b = 2;
    
% Define the time horizon [0,1]
time_horizon = [0, 1];
    
% Define the initial conditions for y, y', and y''
initials = [0; 0; 0];
    
% Define the function handle for the input function u(t)
%sin(t) is a common example of a time-varying function.
% You can change the definition of u to any other function of time,
% such as a constant, a step function, or a more complex function, depending on your needs
    
u = @(t) sin(t);
    
% Define the function handle for the system of ODEs
odefunction = @(t, y) ode_system(t, y, a, b, u);
    
% Solve the ODEs using ode45
[t, y] = ode45(odefunction, time_horizon, initials);
    
% Plot the solution
plot(t, y(:,1), '-', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('t');
ylabel('y');
    
function dydt = ode_system(t, y, a, b, u)
    
%Define the system of ODEs
    
dydt = [y(2); y(3); -b*y(3) + u(t) - a*y(1)];
    
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a maths question than a Matlab one.

We would like to rewrite our ODE equation so that there is a single time derivative on the left-hand side and no derivatives on the right.
Currently we have:

```
y'''(t)+ay(t)=-by''(t)+u(t)
```

By letting z = y' and x = z' (= y''), we can rewrite this as:

```
x'(t)+a y(t)=-b x(t)+u(t)
```

So now we have 3 equations in the form:

```
y' = z
z' = x
x' = -b * x + u - a *y
```

We can also think of this as a vector equation where v = (y, z, x).
The right-hand side would then be,

```
v(1)' = v(2)
v(2)' = v(3)
v(3)' = -b * v(3) + u - a * v(1)
```

which is what you have in the question.